# Should I landscape this table to fit page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
  % The input with the comma as group separator,
  % \num{2,944} (almost three thousand), can be supported by options:
  % input-decimal-markers={.},
  % input-ignore={,},
}

\DeclareSIUnit{\ugpcm}{\micro\gram\per\cubic\meter}
% u for micro (\ug is an abbreviation in package siunit for micro gram)
% g for gram
% p for per
% c for cubic
% m for meter

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  % The optional argument with a shorter version (it's still quite long)
  % for the list of tables
  \caption[Annual average concentrations of the air pollutants
    and traffic indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation
    coefficients]
  {Annual average concentrations of air pollutants and traffic
    indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation coefficients
    (N = \num{2944}).
    Current European air quality standards (1~year average):
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{25}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).
    WHO recommendations (1~year average):
    \SI{20}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{10}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).}
  \label{aggiungi}
  \begin{tabular}{
     l
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
   }
   \setlength{\mylength}{30cm}
    \toprule
     Descriptives & \multicolumn{11}{c}               {Spearman correlation coefficients} \\
    \cmidrule{2-12}
    Exposure (\si{\micro\gram/m^3}) & {Mean} & {SD} & {5th centile}  & {Median}  & {95th centile} & {PM10}  
                                                   & {PMCoarse} & {PM25} & {PM25abs} & {NOX} & {NO2} \\
    \midrule
    PM10  & 20.38    & 2.42  & 16.45 & 20.49 & 24.32 & 1 \\
    PMCoarse  & 6.24   & 1.08    & 4.84  & 6.07  & 8.44 & 0.76 & 1  \\
    PM2.5  & 13.55    & 0.85  & 12.5  & 13.4  & 15.29 & 0.43    & 0.32  & 1 \\ 
    PM2.5abs  & 1.69   & 0.17    & 1.46  & 1.67  & 1.99 & 0.67  & 0.84  & 0.48 & 1 \\
    NOX  & 32.7   & 7.28    & 23.83 & 31.34 & 46.66 & 0.69  & 0.85  & 0.48  & 0.76  & 1 \\
    NO2  & 18.77    & 3.83  & 13.76 & 18.28 & 25.62 & 0.67  & 0.79  & 0.45  & 0.66  & 0.92  & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your code cannot compile: the number of columns is inconsistent: you declare `6` columns and use up to `12`!

Answer (score 1):

Your table can be fit in portrait page if:

- correct all missmathes in table code
- use smaller font (`\small`)
- reduce space between columns
- longer column heads broke to two lines

If this is acceptable, than you will obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\ugpcm}{\micro\gram\per\cubic\meter}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}% <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{rotating}% <-- added

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  % The optional argument with a shorter version (it's still quite long)
  % for the list of tables
  \caption[Annual average concentrations of the air pollutants
    and traffic indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation
    coefficients]
  {Annual average concentrations of air pollutants and traffic
    indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation coefficients
    (N = \num{2944}).
    Current European air quality standards (1~year average):
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{25}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).
    WHO recommendations (1~year average):
    \SI{20}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{10}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).}
  \label{aggiungi}
    \small
  \begin{tabular}{
     l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
     S[table-format=2.2]
     S[table-format=1.2]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
    *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
     S[table-format=1.0]
   }
    \toprule
     Descriptives & \multicolumn{11}{c}{Spearman correlation coefficients} \\
    \cmidrule{2-12}
   \makecell[l]{Exposure\\ (\si{\ugpcm})}
        & {Mean} & {SD} & {\makecell{5th\\ centile}} & {Median} 
            & {\makecell{95th\\ centile}} & {PM10} & {PMCoarse} & {PM25} 
                & {PM25abs} & {NOX} & {NO2} \\
    \midrule
    PM10  & 20.38    & 2.42  & 16.45 & 20.49 & 24.32 & 1 \\
    PMCoarse  & 6.24   & 1.08    & 4.84  & 6.07  & 8.44 & 0.76 & 1  \\
    PM2.5  & 13.55    & 0.85  & 12.5  & 13.4  & 15.29 & 0.43    & 0.32  & 1 \\
    PM2.5abs  & 1.69   & 0.17    & 1.46  & 1.67  & 1.99 & 0.67  & 0.84  & 0.48 & 1 \\
    NOX  & 32.7   & 7.28    & 23.83 & 31.34 & 46.66 & 0.69  & 0.85  & 0.48  & 0.76  & 1 \\
    NO2  & 18.77    & 3.83  & 13.76 & 18.28 & 25.62 & 0.67  & 0.79  & 0.45  & 0.66  & 0.92  & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In case, that this is not an option, you can use `sidewaystable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
  % The input with the comma as group separator,
  % \num{2,944} (almost three thousand), can be supported by options:
  % input-decimal-markers={.},
  % input-ignore={,},
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\ugpcm}{\micro\gram\per\cubic\meter}

\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{makecell}% <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}% <-- added

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption[Annual average concentrations of the air pollutants
    and traffic indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation
    coefficients]
  {Annual average concentrations of air pollutants and traffic
    indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation coefficients
    (N = \num{2944}).
    Current European air quality standards (1~year average):
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{25}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).
    WHO recommendations (1~year average):
    \SI{20}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{10}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).}
  \label{aggiungi}
    \small
  \begin{tabular}{
     l %@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
     S[table-format=2.2]
     S[table-format=1.2]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
    *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
     S[table-format=1.0]
   }
    \toprule
     Descriptives & \multicolumn{11}{c}{Spearman correlation coefficients} \\
    \cmidrule{2-12}
   Exposure (\si{\ugpcm})
        & {Mean} & {SD} & {5th  centile} & {Median} 
            & {95th centile} & {PM10} & {PMCoarse} & {PM25} 
                & {PM25abs} & {NOX} & {NO2} \\
    \midrule
    PM10  & 20.38    & 2.42  & 16.45 & 20.49 & 24.32 & 1 \\
    PMCoarse  & 6.24   & 1.08    & 4.84  & 6.07  & 8.44 & 0.76 & 1  \\
    PM2.5  & 13.55    & 0.85  & 12.5  & 13.4  & 15.29 & 0.43    & 0.32  & 1 \\
    PM2.5abs  & 1.69   & 0.17    & 1.46  & 1.67  & 1.99 & 0.67  & 0.84  & 0.48 & 1 \\
    NOX  & 32.7   & 7.28    & 23.83 & 31.34 & 46.66 & 0.69  & 0.85  & 0.48  & 0.76  & 1 \\
    NO2  & 18.77    & 3.83  & 13.76 & 18.28 & 25.62 & 0.67  & 0.79  & 0.45  & 0.66  & 0.92  & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]